# Create 'dummy' edges for missing edges in edge list

Tags: r, edge-list

I have a collection of nodes, each associated with a given year like this:

```
nodes <- data.frame(name = c("a1","a2","a3","a4","a5","b1","b2","b3","b4","c1","c2"),
                    yr =   c("yr1","yr2","yr3","yr4","yr5","yr2","yr3","yr4","yr5","yr4","yr5"))
```

```
   name  yr
1    a1 yr1
2    a2 yr2
3    a3 yr3
4    a4 yr4
5    a5 yr5
6    b1 yr2
7    b2 yr3
8    b3 yr4
9    b4 yr5
10   c1 yr4
11   c2 yr5
```

To help visualize this, look to the table below, where each column is a year and each row is a group of nodes.

```
data.frame(
  yr1 = c("a1",NA,NA),
  yr2 = c("a2","b1",NA),
  yr3 = c("a3","b2",NA),
  yr4 = c("a4","b3","c1"),
  yr5 = c("a5","b4","c2"))
```

```
   yr1  yr2  yr3 yr4 yr5
1   a1   a2   a3  a4  a5
2 <NA>   b1   b2  b3  b4
3 <NA> <NA> <NA>  c1  c2
```

Now imagine this as an edge list where the node in yr1 is connected to the node in yr2 and so-on. The edge list will look like this:

```
edges <- data.frame(source = c("a1","a2","a3","a4","b1","b2","b3","c1"),
                    target = c("a2","a3","a4","a5","b2","b3","b4","c2"))
```

```
  source target
1     a1     a2
2     a2     a3
3     a3     a4
4     a4     a5
5     b1     b2
6     b2     b3
7     b3     b4
8     c1     c2
```

What I want to do is to fill in the missing edges with dummy edges. It's easier to visualize using the first table. So it would look like this when all the 'NA' values are replace with the dummies:

```
data.frame(
  yr1 = c("a1","01","01"),
  yr2 = c("a2","b1","02"),
  yr3 = c("a3","b2","03"),
  yr4 = c("a4","b3","c1"),
  yr5 = c("a5","b4","c2"))
```

```
  yr1 yr2 yr3 yr4 yr5
1  a1  a2  a3  a4  a5
2  01  b1  b2  b3  b4
3  01  02  03  c1  c2
```

In the edge list version of the data, it would look like this:

```
edges_new <- data.frame(source = c("a1","a2","a3","a4","01","b1","b2","b3","01","02","03","c1"),
                        target = c("a2","a3","a4","a5","b1","b2","b3","b4","02","03","c1","c2"))
```

```
   source target
1      a1     a2
2      a2     a3
3      a3     a4
4      a4     a5
5      01     b1
6      b1     b2
7      b2     b3
8      b3     b4
9      01     02
10     02     03
11     03     c1
12     c1     c2
```

So to summarize, given the 'nodes' data frame and the 'edges' data frame, how can I calculate 'edges_new'? I can figure it out in the wide version of the table where each year has its own column. In that case I could just use a series of if_else functions. But I'm not sure how to do it from an edge list.

Here are the three data frames together:

```
nodes <- data.frame(name = c("a1","a2","a3","a4","a5","b1","b2","b3","b4","c1","c2"),
                    yr =   c("yr1","yr2","yr3","yr4","yr5","yr2","yr3","yr4","yr5","yr4","yr5"))
edges <- data.frame(source = c("a1","a2","a3","a4","b1","b2","b3","c1"),
                    target = c("a2","a3","a4","a5","b2","b3","b4","c2"))
edges_new <- data.frame(source = c("a1","a2","a3","a4","01","b1","b2","b3","01","02","03","c1"),
                        target = c("a2","a3","a4","a5","b1","b2","b3","b4","02","03","c1","c2"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The workflow might be

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

nodes %>%
  mutate(grp = substr(name, 1, 1)) %>%
  complete(grp, yr) %>%
  mutate(name = coalesce(name, sprintf('%02d', match(yr, unique(yr))))) %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  transmute(source = name, target = lead(name)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  drop_na()
```

```
# A tibble: 12 × 3
   grp   source target
   <chr> <chr>  <chr> 
 1 a     a1     a2    
 2 a     a2     a3    
 3 a     a3     a4    
 4 a     a4     a5    
 5 b     01     b1    
 6 b     b1     b2    
 7 b     b2     b3    
 8 b     b3     b4    
 9 c     01     02    
10 c     02     03    
11 c     03     c1    
12 c     c1     c2
```

Comment: Thank you! In my actual data, it's not as easy to identify a grouping variable. For instance, instead of a1,a2,a3,a4,a5 the IDs might be 11947, 246046, 406753, etc. Is there a way to do this if you can't just use the node name to derive a grouping variable? Otherwise this solution will work perfectly

Comment: @Obed How about using `yr` to identify a grouping variable? E.g. Replace `mutate(grp = substr(name, 1, 1))` with `mutate(grp = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(as.numeric(sub('yr', '', yr))) <= 0)))`